# struts2 parameters invalid chunk ignored

Tags: struts2

I am working on a project in struts 2, hibernate. I am using jqgrid (json data).
I have upgraded my struts version to 2.3.16
(previously 2.1.8) and jquery grid and jquery version to  3.7.0 , which solved my previous problems(caused by version mismatch).

But right now, I am getting an error and my jqgrid data not getting displayed.

```
   mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar, struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA.jar, commons-      collections-3.2.jar,
 commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar, commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar,
 commons-logging-api-1.1.jar,
 struts2-core-2.3.16.jar,
 xwork-core-2.3.16.jar,
 ognl-3.0.6.jar,
 javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar,
 freemarker-2.3.19.jar,
 commons-fileupload-1.3.jar,
 commons-io-2.2.jar, commons-lang3-3.1.jar,
 commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, asm-3.3.jar, asm-commons-3.3.jar, struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar,    struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.0.jar, struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16.jar
```

I am using tomcat 6.0.35.

I have upgraded my struts version to 2.3.16 (previously 2.1.8) and jquery grid and jquery version to 3.7.0 , which solved my previous problems(caused by version mismatch).

But right now, I am getting an error and my jqgrid data not getting displayed.

the log:
here is the log

```
Feb 18, 2014 4:03:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters
INFO: Invalid chunk starting at byte [0] and ending at byte [0] with a value of [null] ignored
```

I have updated the json plugin to 2.3.16, but that didn't help.

my library structure -

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar,
struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA.jar, commons-collections-3.2.jar,
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar, commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar,
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar,
struts2-core-2.3.16.jar,
xwork-core-2.3.16.jar,
ognl-3.0.6.jar,
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar,
freemarker-2.3.19.jar,
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar,
commons-io-2.2.jar, commons-lang3-3.1.jar,
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, asm-3.3.jar, asm-commons-3.3.jar, struts2-jquery- grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar, struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.0.jar, struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16.jar
```

I am using tomcat 6.0.35.

Comment: This isn't enough information to help.

Comment: Have you checked whether that JSON data is coming or not ?

Comment: No, the Json data is not getting displayed on the jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor bug that was introduced in Apache 6.0.35 and fixed in Apache 6.0.36.  See this link for more information

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-32498